# Android google analytics keep session alive

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

My app plays audio books and therefore there might be about an hour without users activity but I want to know in google analytics how long the app in use (session duration). I've tried to set timeout about 5000 secs, but it doesn't work and probably is not a good way... 
Is there a way to send to google analytics messages like "I'm still alive" ?

Comment: Have it keep track locally and when the user uses one of your online services, upload the data with it? Personally I love audiobooks but I wouldn't want a player that doesn't involve streaming to try and connect to the internet all the time.

Comment: That's not really how the SDK works. They are just posts to the measurement protocol.  there's really nothing to keep alive.   When they are done just post another screenview or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: it's an option in google analytics webUI.
www.google.com/analytics/web/#management/Settings/**ID**/%3Fm.page%3DTrackingSessionSettings/